# Update sibling component in JSF 2 / Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have the following component tree on my page

```
form
    tabView
        datatable
        dialog
```

Now I want to update the dialog component when a row is selected in the datatable.

I tried something like:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@parent:detailsView" oncomplete="detailsViewDialog.show()" />
```

where detailsView is the id of a panelGroup within the p:dialog.

Only having update="@parent" works but is it not a solution to always reload the whole table only to display the dialog.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data table is by itself a `NamingContainer` component, so it's hard to use a relative client ID. You'd basically need to specify the absolute client ID:

```
<p:ajax ... update=":formId:tabViewId:detailsView" />
```

Alternatively, you could also bind the [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) with ID `detailsView` to the view by `binding` attribute and use `UIComponent#getClientId()` in the `update` attribute:

```
<p:ajax ... update=":#{detailsView.clientId}" />
...
<h:panelGroup id="detailsView" binding="#{detailsView}">
```

Comment: Do I need a backing property for the binding? It didn't work for me

Comment: @Lule: Nope. Then you've a different problem than asked here.